# How to show like and dislike on a View?

Tags: views, 8

How I can show [Like & dislike](https://www.drupal.org/project/like_and_dislike) button on a view in drupal 8?

If the view is of content type then Like & dislike show but with all fields of content.

If we select views as a field type then there is no option to add Like & dislike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/like_dislike. I just tested it with a view and it works perfectly.

Comment: Iam installed and used https://www.drupal.org/project/like_dislike but is has several bug like on view page count not update secondly anonymous user can unlimited vote on node view page.So there is any solutions for https://www.drupal.org/project/like_dislike.

Comment: that working :)